# Why is shear force indeterminate at a section where point load acts

Tags: statics, structural-beam

Why is shear force indeterminate at a section where a point load acts, i understand it from the mathematical point of view, since the left and right hand limits would not agree and would lead to discontinuity at such a point, but i am not able to grasp it fully,i don't get intuition for it.

Also, why is bending  moment indeterminate at a point where a couple is applied.

Comment: A point load is a mathematical concept. In real life here is **always** a pressure distribution at the contact that spans a finite distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These loadings are not indeterminate, in the sense that we don't know what they are, because their magnitudes can be calculated quite readily.  It's just that they change in magnitude quite abruptly due to the nature of a point loading, and are more accurately termed 'discontinuous'.

With careful consideration, the abrupt change in magnitudes can even be handled mathematically by use of the proper discontinuous function representation.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean when you say 'Why is shear force indeterminate at a section'. There are only statically indeterminate or determinate structures, not loads ,forces or stresses.

Comment: These are the exact wordings of Irving shames, introduction to solid mechanics

Comment: In one of the problems of the book, where point load acts at x= l/2 , it says "the shear force is indeterminate, since at this position there is a point force" .